# Composer is having ssl issues with private repository on osx

Tags: ssl, mac-osx, ssl-certificate, openssl, composer

there are many similar questions but nothing that helps my cas. We are using a custom self hosted composer repo, for internal libraries. It all worked perfectly fine untill we updated the SSL certificate or the composer repo. Now composer update does not recognize the certificate (due to missing intermediate cert from geotrust). On all linux boxes all I need to do is just add that intermediate certificate to ca-bundle file and it works perfectly fine. The problem is on our develeopment boxes that are running OSX. On osx composer does not use the key chain, so the certificate in there is not used. curl recognizes the cert and so does the browser, only composer has issues. Now there are 2 possible solutions, but I dont know how to achieve either of them:

1)add the missing cert localy for composer (not sure where composer is looking for certs so any path or instructions are appreciated).

2)Preferred solution would be to attach the missing intermediate certificate to the domain certificate on the server, but I  am not sure how to do that so again any links or instructions would be much appreciated).

Comment: `attach the missing intermediate certificate to the domain certificate on the server`, try appending the intermediate certificate at the end of the server's certificate. Take a look at /etc/ssl/certs/ and try `grep -c "BEGIN CERTIFICATE" | grep 4`, if you're lucky enough you'll see at least one certificate that has two embedded certs inside (bundle).

Comment: Thnx, turns out GeoTrust DV certs are not OS recognized. I built the whole chain file and it works perfectly now. Thnx for your help.

Comment: No problem, also previous command should be either `grep -c "CERTIFICATE" | grep 4` or `grep -c "BEGIN CERTIFICATE" | grep 2`, it was a mistake on my part.

Comment: no prob, fugured that out :)

Answer (score 0):

Thnx to ychaouche's answer this was resolved by creating a full certificate chain and adding to the v-host config.